# Increment rows on the basis of CASE statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image]

I am trying to calculate a cumulative column, which would increment only on a combination of equality of 2 columns, I have written using case statement as below:

```
select *,
    CASE WHEN CarID=lag_CarID AND Checkpoint=lag_Checkpoint then
        "Cumulative"="Cumulative" + 1 
        ELSE "Cumulative"="Cumulative" +0 
    END
FROM (query for table where Cumulative has been initialized as a column with value = 0.
```

Result: Case expression is populating as true and false, but all values for the column Cumulative is coming 0. Please help.
Below is my desired output.
Apologies for earlier badly written question.

Comment: Provide a fiddle with some sample data and desured result for it.

Comment: You use a `CASE` **expression** not statement. You should also [edit] the question and include the table and sample data as `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements **not** as am image, **never** use images for that. Add the expected result too, as tabular text.

Comment: I would..but I can't seem to add it as tabular text right out of excel!! And yes I will do the edits as requested. Apologies from an SQL noob guys. Kindly bear!

Comment: I don't understand your expected result - all values for `car_id` and `checkpoint` are the same in all rows - so why isn't `cumulative` incremented for each and every row?

Comment: For your example `signal + 1` does what you want.  Your logic clearly involves more than the two columns -- for instance, a date is ordering the results and `signal` might be involved.  You need to better explain the logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
Just write: 
select *,
CASE WHEN CarID=lag_CarID AND Checkpoint=lag_Checkpoint then
    Cumulative + 1 ELSE Cumulative END
 FROM (query for table where Row_Number has been initialized as a column with value = 0)
```